# Selenium Grayed out Button

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

Hi I'm trying to click on this button that stays disabled until you fill in other fields. I am working with firefox. My script fills out those fields and the button is now clickable with my mouse. But when I try to click that element through selenium I get an error

```
  WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (281.8333282470703, 14.149993896484375). Other element would receive the click: <li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('urlAdm')}" id="adm-menu"></li>
```

Here is the html for the button.

```
   <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ng-binding" ng-disabled="!userForm.$valid || user.deleted_at" disabled="disabled">
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-fw"></i>
      Create
    </button>
    <!-- ngIf: isAddUser() --><button ng-if="isAddUser()" type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="resetForm()">
      <i class="fa fa-eraser fa-fw"></i>
      Clear
    </button><!-- end ngIf: isAddUser() -->
    <!-- ngIf: !user.deleted_at && user.id !== currentUser.id && user.id -->
    <!-- ngIf: user.deleted_at -->
  </div>
```

I've tried regularly clicking on the button and doing it through actions but neither work.

Here is the code

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='user-editor-1']/form/div[5]/div/button[1]")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the error message, you will see what element is blocking the click. What element is that? Is it a popup or something that you can dismiss?

Comment: when i look at the screen i don't see anything covering the button. I can physically click it with my mouse so I'm assuming nothing is covering it. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing it myself. Sometimes if the script is fast enough and the site takes a fraction of a second to hide a popup, etc. the script may see that something is blocking the element but you may just see a flash. I would put a breakpoint on the line before you get the error and see what's going on. You may be able to see it better.

Comment: I would search through the HTML looking for that `LI` that is blocking the button and see what it is. From the id, it may be some admin menu or something?

Comment: I used the wait implicitly function for 2 seconds. Which should be plenty of time to work. But that didn't work either. As a user I am able to click. Unfortunately the site I am working on contains private information so I cannot show it. I might have more questions regarding reasons why this isn't working but for now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `click` using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Create')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

Hope it helps....:)

Comment: high could you explain a little to me what this does?

Comment: @JohnDoe it will click on your desire element using javascript

Comment: @JohnDoe just so you know... using `execute_script()` executes an action that a user cannot perform. Selenium was designed to not be able to interact with hidden elements because the intent is to only allow user scenarios, e.g. users can't click hidden or disabled buttons. JS will allow you to do that but that's obviously no longer a user scenario. If you are OK with that, then that's fine... I just wanted you to be aware in case you weren't already.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. I thought a wait implicitly would fix it, but that didn't work either. This works fine. Thank you so much Jeff!